# Best way to add fill fill/color to hollow text using Photoshop/Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, background, fill

I have a font called Stoney Billy (Schoolhouse Rock?)

I'd like to make the background of the text yellow.

I tried a few different things in Illustrator but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

[image: text attempt in Illustrator]

I ended up using PS, rasterizing the text, and using the paintbucket tool to fill each section between the black lines individually.  (I also can't figure out why the yellow is partially transparent but that's a different problem)

[image: rasterized, filled with paintbucket tool]

This is just an example.  I have a lot of text I need to do this to.  Is there an easier/quicker way to fill the text with color while leaving the black text outline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is merely posted based upon my experience. It *should* work, but as with all art, without direct interaction there *could* always be something undisclosed that even you may not be aware of.

---

Illustrator....

- Select the shapes...
- `Edit > Copy`
- Pathfinder Panel (Window > Pathfinder) Click the **Unite** button.

---

If the above does **not** fill in the hollow areas....

Select the shapes again and choose `Object > Compound Path > Release`.
Then try the Unite button on the Pathfinder Panel again.

Everything should be a solid black.. and be and single shape, holes and all. (Per word if the words are separated.)

---

- Change the fill to yellow
- `Edit > Paste in Front` (which will paste the black key line back in place)

---

You can then merely group everything.

If you would rather unify the shape to remove the yellow areas underneath the black areas... select it all and click the **Merge** button on the Pathfinder Panel.

Comment: Or shape builder and box selection.